# Get custom validation error message from Web Api request to HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following model for my ASP.NET Web Api 2 service:

```
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Message is too long; 10 characters max.")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I am making the request from my WinForms app:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var messageOverTenCharacters = new Message { Text = "OverTenCharacters" }

    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/messenger/PushMessage", messageOverTenCharacters);

    // How do I see my custom error message that I wrote in my model class?
}
```

How do I see my custom error message that I wrote in my model class?

Here is my implementation for my validation class that I'm registering to the web api config:

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your WebAPI controller action test for validity?

Comment: That depends what you did in your controller. What is the implementation of messenger - push message?

Comment: [This may point you in the right direction](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: I know my controller is testing for validity because the `response` has a 400 status code, and the `response.ReasonPhrase` is "Bad Request"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I needed to set the `Response.ReasonPhrase` in my validation class so the client can see it (instead of just "BadRequest"):

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            var errors = actionContext.ModelState
                                      .Values
                                      .SelectMany(m => m.Errors
                                                        .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));

            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);

            actionContext.Response.ReasonPhrase = string.Join("\n", errors);
        }
    }
}
```